# linux extract portion of the string that can be second most common pattern

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I have several strings(or filenames in a directory) and i need to group them by second most common pattern, then i will iterate over them by each group and process them. in the example below i need 2 from ACCEPT and 2 from BASIC_REGIS, bascially from string beginning to one character after hyphen (-) and **it could be any character and not just digit**. The first most common pattern are ACCEPT and BASIC_REGIS. I am looking for second most common pattern using grep -Po (Perl and only-matching). AWK solution is working

### INPUT

```
ACCEPT-zABC-0123
ACCEPT-zBAC-0231
ACCEPT-1ABC-0120
ACCEPT-1CBA-0321

BASIC_REGIS-2ABC-9043
BASIC_REGIS-2CBA-8132
BASIC_REGIS-PCCA-6532
BASIC_REGIS-PBBC-3023
```

### OUTPUT

```
ACCEPT-z
ACCEPT-1

BASIC_REGIS-2
BASIC_REGIS-P
```

---

```
echo "ACCEPT-0ABC-0123"|grep -Po "\K^A.*-"
```

Result :  ACCEPT-0ABC-

but I need :  ACCEPT-0

However awk solution is working

```
echo "ACCEPT-1ABC-0120"|awk '$0 ~ /^A/{print substr($0,1,index($0,"-")+1)}'
```

ACCEPT-1

Comment: Regarding `I am looking for second most common pattern using grep -Po (Perl and only-matching)` - why? If you have a portable, working awk solution as shown in your question, why look for a non-portable solution?

Comment: I was trying to get grep -P (perl) with -o (only matching) to work, the catch is it can be any character after first hyphen (-) and not just a number.

Comment: You don't need `-P` (PCREs) for this, it's trivial with EREs or even BREs. [edit] your question to clarify that you want the first character after the `-`, not the first integer after the `-`, as that's not clear from your question, and update your example to include the case where that character isn't a digit and the case where it's 2 digits but you only want the first one output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `-P` (PCRE) for that, just a plain, old BRE:

```
$ grep -o '^[^-]*-.' file | sort -u
ACCEPT-0
ACCEPT-1
BASIC_REGIS-2
BASIC_REGIS-9
```

Or using GNU awk alone:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/^[^-]*-./,a) && !seen[a[0]]++{print a[0]}' file
ACCEPT-0
ACCEPT-1
BASIC_REGIS-2
BASIC_REGIS-9
```

or any awk:

```
$ awk '!match($0,/^[^-]*-./){next} {$0=substr($0,1,RLENGTH)} !seen[$0]++' file
ACCEPT-0
ACCEPT-1
BASIC_REGIS-2
BASIC_REGIS-9
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
$ grep -Eo '^[^-]+-.' file | sort -u
```

### Output

```
ACCEPT-0
ACCEPT-1
BASIC_REGIS-2
BASIC_REGIS-9
```

### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | the beginning of the string |
| `[^-]+` | any character except: `-` (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `-` | - |
| `.` | any character except \n |

Comment: Thanks @Gilles Quenot, I forgot to mention that, it could have any character after first hyphen (-), for example  ACCEPT-a  or ACCEPT-b

Comment: OK, so my solution should work in this case already

Comment: it breaks and stops as soon as it find a DIGIT for example     echo "abcdef9-a123"|grep -oP '^\D+\d'  outputs ** abcdef9 **  Stops as soon as it finds a digit, it should output abcdef9-a

Comment: Thanks Gilles for explaining, it keeps looking until it finds a digit

Comment: Edited post accordingly

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '
match($0,/^(ACCEPT-[0-9]+|BASIC_REGIS-[0-9]+/) && !arr[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++
' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** With GNU `grep` please try following.

```
grep -oP '^.*?-[0-9]+' Input_file | sort -u
```

Comment: Thanks Ravinder, It was close, since my next digit after hyphen could be anything and (not just digits). i modified a bit and got it to work. can you please explain your solution.

Comment: @syedlaeeq, sure which one you want to get explained kindly do let me know.

Comment: Ravinder, i appreciate you taking time to think through this, I looking at grep -oP, I got  ^ -- beginning, . any character multiple times, not sure why ?  after that since that would meain any character. (I don't need [0-9] (digits) as it may have any character after hyphen(-)

Answer (score 1):

not too sure what you meant by "2nd most common groupings", but to simply replicate that output :

> ```
> {gn}awk '!NF || !__[$-_  = sprintf("%.*s", index($-_,$(!_+!_)),$-_)]++' FS='-'
>    mawk '!NF || !__[$!NF = sprintf("%.*s", index($_, $(!_+!_)),$_) ]++' FS='-'
> ```

```
ACCEPT-0
ACCEPT-1

BASIC_REGIS-2
BASIC_REGIS-9
```

Answer (score 0):

POSIX-shells have primitive parameter expansion. Meaning using this:

```
${string#-*} # Remove first ‘-‘ and everything after
```

In combination with this:

```
${string#*-} # Remove first ‘-‘ and everything before
```

**Can extract the n’th most common pattern.**

For example:

```
input="ACCEPT-0ABC-0123"

common_pattern_base=${input#-*} # Result → ACCEPT
next_level=${input#*-} # Result → 0ABC-0123

common_pattern_mid=${next_level#-*} # Result → 0ABC
next_level_again=${next_level#*-} # Result → 0123
```

Now I did this very crudely, but it should serve as an example on how simple and powerful this tool can be. Especially in combination with a loop.

If you need a certain syntax, you can now simply work with individual pieces:

```
# Result of line below → 0
trim_pattern_mid=“$(echo ${common_pattern_mid} | cut -c1)”

# Result of line below → ACCEPT-0
format=“${common_pattern_base}-${trim_pattern_mid}”
```

While this answer is longer, it is more flexible and simple than using regular-expressions. Imagine wanting to get the 4th-pattern of a 256 long chain with regex, it’s a nightmare.

This answer is more suited for scripting. If it’s ad-hoc, grep or sed will do the job - at least for small patterns.

Comment: As you hinted at, you'd need to add a shell loop to make this applicable to the OPs problem but then see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for why not to do that.

Comment: Thansk guy, I tried various combination of grep extract only matching pattern (-Po). I am looking to find regular expression which will take any character after first hyphen and give me the portion until that character (eg. Guy-abcd-0123-yet  -->    Guy-a

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for the resource, it was a great read and, conceptually I understand the shell better now. The writer put so many things into words that I couldn’t - it was exciting.

Comment: @syedlaeeq yeah, regex is the way to go. I’ll leave my answer up for people to see why my approach is sub-optimal.

Comment: You're welcome. Any time you find a shell answer by [Stéphane](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas) you can be sure it'll be a good one.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more efficient as it's not calling `substr`:

```
awk -v{,O}FS='-' '{printf("%s-%c\n",$1,$2)}' file
```

Comment: just beware of side effects of `"%c"` :  `echo "4567-7971-ABCD" | gawk -e '$!NF = sprintf("%s-[%c][%c][%.1s]\n", $1, $2, $2"", $2)' FS='-'` :::::::::::::::::::::::: ::::::::: ::::::   `4567-[ἣ][7][7]` :::::::::::::: if `$2` just so happens to be all digits, it might print out a multi-byte unicode character instead — so you can either append an empty string after `$2`, or use `"%.1s"` instead, which is always 1st unicode character or 1st byte for malformed `UTF-8` sequence (in byte/`LC_ALL=POSIX/C` modes, it's simply 1st byte)

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk (or some other that supports it?) to not have a space immediately after `-v`.